# Jacobian inverse in robotic

Tags: inverse, jacobian, robotics

In robotics, we have
$v=J\dot q$   ----------------  (1)
to calculate the velocity ($v$) in cartesian space. So, we get.
$\dot q={J^-}^1 v $  ----------------  (2)
where, $v = [v_x, v_y, v_z, \omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z]$.
If I assume the robot only has 5 independent joints. Its jacobian is a 6x5 matrix. In cartesian space, we always have $\omega_z = 0$. So, the $v$ changes to $[v_x, v_y, v_z, \omega_x, \omega_y, 0]$.
When calculating the inverse kinematics, can we change equation (2) to
$\dot q = {J(1:5, :)^-}^1 v(1:5)$  ----------(3)

The result of (2) and (3) is different. It seems the difference comes from J^-1 and  J(1:5, :)^-1. Does anyone know why?
Note: I just take the -1 as the pseudo inverse.
For example. we have one joint arm as
0-----------------------
In general, it's jacobian $J$ is a 6x1 matrix, and its velocity in cartesian space will be $[v_x, v_y, 0, 0, 0, \omega_z]$. So, we clearly know some elements are always 0. If an arbitrary cartesian trajectory $[v_x, v_y, v_z, \omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z]$ is injected in Eqn. (2).
Is that possible to eliminate the impossible 0 elements in advance, then go to inverse kinematics?
In Eqn. (3), is that possible to select the corresponding row of jacobian and velocity directly?

Comment: Hi @RobX, welcome to MSE. Could you please use MathJax to format your equations? Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

be careful about the notation:
$v=J\dot{q}$ (or $dx=Jdq$). Assuming $J$ be invertible you have: $\dot{q}=J^{-1}v$.
When you mention "degrees-of-freedom" in robotics, you need to specify whether you refer to "joint space" or "task space" degrees.  For example, 5 DoFs at the joint space level, means that your robot has 5 (independent) joints, therefore $q$ would have 5 components. Vice-versa, if you refer to 5 DoFs at the task-space level, which I assume here,then your end-effector just has 5 (controllable) DoFs. As such, it is not true that $wz=0$, because $wz$ is just undefined, namely $v$ has 5 components without $w_z$.

Now, to answer your question. Let your task-space velocity vector be $v=[v_x,v_y,v_z,w_x,w_y]$. In this case, if you still have 6 joints, then your robot is redundantly-actuated. Notice that the Jacobian, $J(1:5,:)$, becomes rectangular and not invertible! Therefore, you have multiple solutions to find $\dot{q}$. You may just type in your code $\dot{q}=pinv(J(1:5,:))v$, where pinv() is the pseudo-inverse of $J$. otherwise, for more elegant solutions you may have a look on some Optimisation problems with null-space explorations, see e.g. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84628-642-1
or
https://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Introduction_to_Robotics.html?id=MqMeAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: Hi, Gino, thanks for your answer. Let me make my question much clear. E.g. we have an one joint arm like.

Comment: Hi, Gino, thanks for your answer.   Let me make my question much clear. For example. we have one joint arm as 

0-----------------------
In general, its jacobian J is a 6x1 matrix, and its velocity in cartesian space will be [vx, vy, 0, 0, 0, wz]. So, we clearly know some elements are always 0.   
The problem I met is that an arbitrary cartesian trajectory [vx, vy, vz, wx, wy, wz] is injected. What I want to achieve is to eliminate the impossible element in advance, then go inverse kinematics. Namely, is that possible to select the corresponding row of jacobian and velocity directly?

Comment: Hey Rob, I deduce from what you write that the end-effector is constrained to move in a plane, so you just have two components of linear velocity (v_x, v_y) and one component in angular velocity (w_z). Suppose you assign an arbitrary cartesian trajectory, say [v_x(t), v_y(t), 0, 0,0,w_z(t)], and you want to find the corresponding joint velocity q_dot (t). If you have one controllable joint, you can just control one degree of freedom of the end-effector, namely one component of v. The inverse kinematic problem in this case does not generally have a solution (and the robot is under-actuated).

Comment: My suggestion is:
1) define the number of controllable joints (m) and the number of controllable task space variables (n). Then, if m=n the robot is fully-constrained and J is invertible if the robot is not in a singular configuration. If m<n, the robot is under-actuated and the inverse kinematic (IK) problem does not have exact solution. In this case you can just solve it in an approximate way or, better, just control a subset of v (you can just control m components of v). Lastly, if m>n the robot is redundantly-actuated and the IK problem admits multiple solutions.

Comment: Assume your robot is under-actuated (m<n). m=1 and n=3, like in your previous comment. Then, you can only control one component of v, such as v_x. In this case, you save the first row of the Jacobian matrix and remove all the other raws from 2 to 6. About the columns of J, since you only have one joint, such as joint 1. Then you need to save the column 1 and remove all the others from 2 to 6.   
In general, the i-th row of the Jacobian refer to the i-th component of v, while the j-th column of J refers to the j-th joint variable!  
Hope it clarifies :)!

Comment: To finish, I realised you changed the question. The reason why you get different results between (2) and (3) is because in (3) you are removing one row of the Jacobian, therefore you are controlling only 5 DoFs of the end-effector and you do not care about the 6th component of v. The robot becomes fully-constrained and you get an exact solution. In (2), instead, the robot is under-actuated and your 5 joints are stuggling to control the 6 DOFs of the end.effector (i.e. to keep the 6th component of v to be zero). The pseudoinverse is an approximate solution (it minimises the square of the error)

Comment: Did you understand the difference between (2) and (3) now? In 3, you are not considering the 6th component of v, while in (2) the joints try to make it 0. This is different because in (2) is fully constrained m=n, while (3) is m<n (under-constrained). According to what you wrote, method (3) is the right one for your case!